# How to know customer's order choose which shipping method with shipment id

Tags: magento2.3, shipping, shipment-tracking

I developed a custom module so that customers can choose the logistics methods provided by the plugin, and these logistics methods all have a unified CarrierCode.
But how do I know if the order comes from my custom logistics method when the user tracks shipment so that I can provide them with logistics information.

May be I need to change details.phtml in module-shipping,
`\vendor\magento\module-shipping\view\frontend\templates\tracking\details.phtml`
.But in this page I don't know which shipping method it use,juse know $track['number'],or $shipmentId in parent page.

So,how can i get shipping method they used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to add information based on the `carrier code`.

When creating a shipment, if you add tracking details, then you have `carrier_code` in there. Check this table:

Check `\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\email\shipment\track.phtml`. This is the file responsible for sending `tracking detail` in shipment email.

And you can get the carrier code inside the tracking loop:

```
$_item->getCarrierCode()
```

To customize this file, just copy the file to your theme:

`/app/design/frontend/YourTheme/ThemeName/tempaltes/email/shipment/track.phtml`

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

In order to add tracking info to your custom shipping method, you should add `getTrackingInfo($trackingNumber)` function in your carrier (`Namespace/Module/Model/Carrier/YourCarrier.php`).

```
/**
 * Get tracking information. Original return value annotation is misleading.
 *
 * @see \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier::isTrackingAvailable()
 * @see \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline::getTrackingInfo()
 * @see \Magento\Dhl\Model\Carrier::getTracking()
 * @param string $trackingNumber
 * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\AbstractResult
 */
public function getTrackingInfo($trackingNumber)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\Status $tracking */
    $tracking = $this->trackStatusFactory->create();

    $title = $this->getConfigData('title');

    $tracking->setCarrier($this->_code); //your carrier code
    $tracking->setCarrierTitle($title);
    $tracking->setTracking($trackingNumber);

    //you may want to add the events coming from your api
    $trackEventsData [] =
        [
            'deliverydate' => 'date',
            'deliverytime' => 'time',
            'deliverylocation' => 'location',
            'activity' => 'activity'
        ];
    $tracking->setStatus(isset($trackEventsData[0]) ? $trackEventsData[0]['activity'] : '');
    $tracking->setProgressdetail($trackEventsData);

    return $tracking;
}
```

Comment: Think you for your answer.

Comment: Think you for your answer. I think your code can help me tu send email with TrackingUrl.But I dont't know how to add this url.And I'm trying to add tracking message in web when customer open tracking information page.I can useing track id to visit my shipping carrier Api to get shipping log.So ,may be you can tell me how to get carrierCode in \vendor\magento\module-shipping\view\frontend\templates\tracking\details.phtml or \vendor\magento\module-shipping\view\frontend\templates\tracking\popup.phtml.Think you for your help.

Comment: Plez check my update.

Comment: think you.And a new question.After I writed
\Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory $trackStatusFactory
$this->trackStatusFactory
in my __construct(){}
my website is die.Said 
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Forkel\CustomShipping\Model\Carrier\Custom

What's worng with my code.I'm a new coder for magento2 ,many thing is difficult.
Thank you again.

Comment: You need to compile your code. Run `magento setup:di:compile`.

Comment: Thank you so much. My code is running;